# How to skip line with comment (# space ) in bash for loop

Tags: linux, bash, unix

With the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
export LC_ALL=C

for input_file in $(<inputflist.txt)
do
    case "$input_file" in \#*) continue ;; esac
    echo $input_file

done
```

And `inputflist.txt` with the following content:

```
# foo.txt
bar.txt
```

I expect it to just print the last line `bar.txt` but it prints this instead:

```
foo.txt
bar.txt
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
   [[ $line =~ ^[[:blank:]]*# ]] && continue
   echo "$line"
done < inputflist.txt
```

**Output:**

```
bar.txt
```

Comment: `[[:blank:]]*` is useless here, `$line` doesn't have the leading white spaces, it loses any indentation here (as `IFS` isn't set properly). So deleting that part of the regex will yield to same result.

Comment: That's right, thanks for your comment. It needs `IFS=` before `read` to preserve whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

[Don't read lines with for](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor), use a while loop instead:

```
while IFS= read -r line;do
[[ $line =~ ^[[:space:]]*# ]] || echo "$line"
done <file
```

Note:

1. If you don't set the `IFS` properly, you will lose any indentation.
2. [You should almost always use the -r option with read](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: `[[:space:]]` also matches newlines

Comment: @anubhava that doesn't make any difference here, does it?

Comment: That was just a **fyi comment**. Yes it won't impact this script since `$line` doesn't have any newlines.

Comment: I like the OP's `case` statement better than the `[[` regex, though.

Comment: @tripleee that case method won't delete indented lines.

Comment: True; the regex facility allows for a more versatile expression.

Answer (score 2):

what's wrong in

```
for input_file in $(grep -v "^#" inputflist.txt); do
  echo $input_file
done
```

or simply

```
grep -v "^#" inputflist.txt
```

?

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor explains what's wrong with the first one. The second is fine.

Comment: Oh and in the first, your quoting is broken, too; [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)